# Running PHP in ubuntu terminal not working anymore

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying a PHP script in the terminal yesterday but it didn't work. Not thinking the script could have errors i reinstalled php7.0-cli and when installing it asked something about how i want to do something, i can´t remember what it asked for exactly. Anyhow i pressed the use local something option and after that i´m not finding my mysqli when trying to run the PHP file in terminal.

I´m getting a error like this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/mysite/system/library/db/mysqli.php:7

I have tried reinstalling the PHP extensions and i have tried to uncomment the extensions from my php.ini file.

Comment: You overwrote your php.ini with the default one from the package most likely. Restore from backup.

Comment: Have you re-installed `php7.0-mysql`?

Comment: Tried with apt-get remove php7.0-mysql and then reinstalled it. Doesn´t work.

Comment: Restore from backup how? Not having 1 at the moment.